# Google Tag Manager Parameter Passing

Tags: android, ios, google-tag-manager, double-click-advertising, google-floodlight

I am trying to pass a parameter to google tag manager iOS in order to track conversions.

According to DCM documentation (Double Click Manager). We need to make sure the dc_rdid field is set in order to track conversions.

So far, we have successfully Added the DCM Tag in GTM, the tag is being triggered via an "AppLaunch" event. We can see hits going from the app to DC but the dc_rdid is left blank, see output console below:

```
2016-12-21 10:27:12.883 myApp[XXX:XXXXXX] GoogleTagManager verbose: Successfully sent hit: https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/activity/src=5XXXXX;type=count;cat=ios-a0;ord=1;num=26XXXXXXXXXX;dc_muid=;dc_lat=1
```

Could you advise how to ensure the dc_rdid parameter gets populated?

From the DCM documentation:

> dc_rdid=: User resettable device identifiers in the form of IDFA for
>   iOS or advertising ID (AdID) for Android. This parameter is required.
>   The publisher must pass a value into this parameter in order to enable
>   in-app conversion tracking. The values should be the unhashed, raw
>   value. We will only accept values passed securely over SSL-enabled
>   tags.
>
> Note: We strongly recommend using the dc_rdid parameter for device IDs
>   instead of the legacy parameter dc_muid, which accepts uppercase
>   MD5-hashed IDFA, Android ID, and AdID values.

FYI: we are not using Firebase.

Comment: What version of GTM are you using?

Comment: I am using the "Legacy" SDK for iOS v3.15

Comment: Are you linking the adSupport framework, and the libAdIdAccess.a in your application?